# Browserstack protractor ignores expect

Tags: javascript, protractor, chai, e2e-testing, browserstack

I am using Mocha and Chai.
my e2e runs on browser stack and record nicely (video and all) BUT browser stack always marks the session as completed and no error when I know that some specs failed.

I have tried the example here: https://github.com/browserstack/protractor-browserstack and same result (test marked as completed even when there is an error).

I have tried using 'updateJob' from 'driverProviders/browserStack'...

this is my test:

```
describe('bbbb', () => {
  it('aaa', () => {
    expect(true).to.equal(false);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @BountyHunter suggested, I have used the api to mark tests.
this is the jest of the code (might be some syntax errors)

```
afterEach(function() {
  if (this.currentTest.state === 'failed') {
    //collect error data into array
    //this.currentTest.title, this.currentTest['err']
  }
});

after(function () {
  //after all is done if errors array is not empty, report to browserstack 
  protractor.browser.driver.getSession().then((session) => {
    var request = require("request");
    request({uri: "https://USERNAME:ACCESS_KEY@api.browserstack.com/automate/sessions/"+session['id_']+".json", method:"PUT", form:{"status":"failed","reason":errorsArrayStringified }})
  });

})
```

full repo here: https://github.com/zeevgl/protractor-browserstack

Answer (score 1):

You may create a common hook that executes after each test. Pass the result for your assert/expect, session ID for the driver instance to the hook and make the following API call:

```
var request = require("request");
request({uri: "https://USERNAME:ACCESS_KEY@api.browserstack.com/automate/sessions/<session-id>.json", method:"PUT", form:{"status":"failed","reason":"<reason for failure>"}})
```

This will ensure your test failure is marked on browserstack and with any additional reason text you wish to pass

You may get the session ID using the following code snippet:

```
protractor.browser.driver.getSession().then((session) => {
  console.log(session);
});
```

Comment: how do I know what is my session Id during the test?

Comment: this works, but I don't want to report the issues myself..  I want it to react to the failing expectation

Comment: I reviewed the protractor repo... it seems there is an inbuilt method for marking test failures: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/18d06e8b95c9e29ad9ecd15c309c7302d61b1c5e/lib/driverProviders/browserStack.ts, you only need to ensure your config file uses the username and key capabilities as mentioned here: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/7da9c3a910bb000b30bf9ba82ef48c64bd751709/spec/errorTest/browserStackAuthentication.js

Comment: already tried it. when setting the username and key outside the capabilities it reports failing specs but only in the 'single' mode example that browser stack provides. it does not work in the local one.